# Edit HTML of woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I was going through my cart.php template converting the table to div's.

[Now my cart looks like this with various words not wrapped in any tags - which makes it impossible to style.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdOE.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
/**
 * Cart Page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <?php
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="product-remove">
                            <?php
                                // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                ), $cart_item_key );
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                        }

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data.
                        echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                        }
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                        } else {
                            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                'min_value'    => '0',
                                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                            ), $_product, false );
                        }

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                        <div class="coupon">
                            <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
</form>

<div class="cart-collaterals">
    <?php
        /**
         * Cart collaterals hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_cross_sell_display
         * @hooked woocommerce_cart_totals - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Comment: Is this just the cart.php template?

Comment: Yes it is default woocommerce file